# LWC: What's wrong with the Wire Return code?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Problem is with this line in JS code inside result function-
return this.wirestoredrecords.data.LastName;

I am trying to get the Contact Fields Values using Getter and display in the HTML. PLS HELP.

````
**JS CODE:**

import { api, LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Name from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';
import LastName from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import Phone from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';

const contactfields = [Name, LastName, Phone];

export default class WireGetRecords extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    datavalue;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: contactfields })
    wirestoredrecords;

    get result(){

        return this.wirestoredrecords.data.LastName;

    }

}

**HTML CODE:**
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div>{recordId}</div>
        <div>{result}</div>
        <div></div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>```
````

Comment: What is the error you are gettting?

Comment: Hi @Tushar , I am getting below error-
Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'LastName')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your component loads to the page and the `@wire` is called.
2. The component doesn't wait for `@wire` to finish, it'll be done when it'll be done, asynchronous. Your component carries on.
3. It encounters the html rendering, calls your getter. Well, the variable is undefined/null at that point, `@wire` didn't return yet. The code tries to do `null.data` and throws because null/undefined doesn't have fields.
4. Boom, headshot.

Put some null checking in the getter or use the [`?.` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: How to use in my case, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Try `this.wirestoredrecords?.data?.LastName;` or `return this.wirestoredrecords && this.wirestoredrecords.data ? this.wirestoredrecords.data.LastName : 'Loading...':`

Comment: OMGGG, this line worked - return this.wirestoredrecords?.data?.fields?.Name?.value; But how. Why it worked with that symbol? I will study more on it. Thanks a ton @eyescream.